# How to customize the error messages from aws-amplify-react-native

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-native-ios, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify-react-native to login my app. I have direct used this in my screens by importing all the components.

Here now I need to customize the error messages for this.

Any option to customize the error message.

For example: If the user has no network it will show network error as blindly. But the end user can't able to catch this.

Also in the signup/Forgot passwordx screens the keyboard hided the error message

```
<Authenticator
          hideDefault
          usernameAttributes={__DEV__ ? "email" : "phone_number"}
          amplifyConfig={awsmobile}
          theme={this.state.theme}
          signUpConfig={signUpConfig}
          onStateChange={this.onStateChange}
        >
            <Loading/>
            <SignIn/>
            <ConfirmSignIn/>
            <VerifyContact/>
            <SignUp signUpConfig={signUpConfig}/>
            <ConfirmSignUp/>
            <ForgotPassword/>
            <RequireNewPassword />
            <Greetings/>
        </Authenticator>
```